# MVC 4 specific columns for roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, relational-database, roles

I am looking for a way to implement a login system with use of .NET classes like WebSecurity because the use of them it looks strait forward. I need login system with different roles and i am using EF code first approach MVC 4.

The problem is that I don't know how should I represent users in different roles.
Here is an example:

**Member** is regular registered user. He has **Username**, **Password**, **Email**, **Address**, **Name**, **Surname** etc. He can also order things.

**Admin** is just admin he has some things in common with member like **username** and **password**, but he does not have **Address**, **Name**, **Surname** and can not order things.
On the other hand admin can publish news.

I could simply put all this in one class called User and have a lot of null values for both admin and member, but i think it is pretty silly approach.

I also can see i could have two different classes Member and Admin not related to each other. But it is not an option for me since i want to use the roles implemented in .NET.

(The last think that came to my mind is to inherit from some base class, but i have no idea if it is possible to do and to have relational database as a result.)

So what am i asking for is some standard or/and clever way to create model in MVC 4 to which i can connect with WebSecurity and use all those fancy methods it offers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest using the name "Customer" instead of "Member" as Customer is a more accurate description - I'm assuming by "order things" you are dealing with a storefront.

```
public abstract class User
{
//All of the shared properties go here
}

public class Customer : User
{
//Customer specific properties
}

public class Admin : User
{
//Admin specific properties
}
```

This is basic polymorphism, and Entity Framework can handle it just fine.  Marking the User class abstract indicates to EF that you won't be storing objects that are only users.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to have at least four tables to do this:

1. UserProfile - This will contain Username, Email, Name, etc. and the Key will be a unique Identifier. (I usually use Int)
2. MemberData - This will contain password (hashed of course) and login information (Password reset, confirmation key, etc).  These are seperated for two reasons.  1) Editing the UserProfile will not effect login.  2) Decoupling login data.  You can now let your user login with Username or email address without changing your underlying archetecture.  The key of this table is a foreign key related to they key of the UserProfile Table
3. Roles - This will contain your role data.  All that is needed is an Id (Unique Int), and a Name.
4. UsersInRoles - This table will contain two columns: UserId and RoleId.  This way a user can be assigned to as many or as few roles as needed.

---

Example:

```
UserProfile:
Id    Username    Email
1     user        user@user.com

MemberData:
Id   Password    LastLogin
1    Tx8gke08    08-16-2013

Roles:
Id   Name
1    User
2    Admin

UsersInRoles
UserId    RoleId
1         1
1         2
```

**Side Note:**
The web security framework already contains a way to do all of this.  The [Roles class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) contains methods for creating, deleting, and adding Users.  It is also a standard part of the security package that is created with a default MVC 4 project.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserBase
{
    public string userName ;
    public string password ;

}

class Member : UserBase
{
    public string Email
    public string Address ;
    public string Name ;
    public string Surname ;
}
```

create a single **Users** table with **userName,password,Email,Address,Name,Surname,TypeOfUser**

the columns **Email,Address,Name,Surname,** will accept `null` values

Then you can query the **Users** table and based on the column **TypeOfUser** you can instance a **UserBase** or **Member**

when updating or inserting a **UserBase** then the columns **Email,Address,Name,Surname,** will be set to null, otherwise they will have the value of the **Member** properties

Answer (score 0):

1) Create two roles `Admin` and `Member`. For `Admin` role you need nothing, but `Member` you should extend
2) Create class Member:

```
public class Member
{
public int memberid {get; set;}
public Guid UserId {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
public string phone {get; set;}
.....
}
```

As you may see, you just need to connect it with `asp_net User class` by `Guid UserId`. Everytime, when you use `User` in Role `Member` you can get additonal information from `Member class` by `UserID`.

To acces UserId property from User class use:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
Guid currentUserID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```